# Using C preprocessor to create multiple table layouts

Tags: c, gcc, preprocessor

I need to lay out multiple tables (and structs) based on a common set of definitions.  In order to keep everything consistent, I'd like to keep all the definitions in a single place and use the magic of C macros to expand the definitions into various tables (and structs).

There's one catch: not all of the tables are the same length.  A simplified statement of the problem goes like this:

```
// Here is the master list of things
#define THING_DEFINITIONS \
  THING(apple, true) \
  THING(pear, true) \
  THING(caddilac, false) \
  THING(mango, true)

// I want a table of all thing names -- this works fine
#undef THING
#define THING(name, is_fruit) #name,
char *all_things[] = {
  THING_DEFINITIONS
};

// Now I want a table of just fruits -- the following does not work
#undef THING
#define THING(name, is_fruit) \
#if is_fruit \
 #name,      \
#endif

char *just_fruits[] = {
  THING_DEFINITIONS
};
```

The problem, of course, is that conditionals cannot appear inside of a macro definition, at least not the way it's shown here.

Is there a definition for `THING` such that when I expand `THING_DEFINITIONS` that it only emits fruits?

Comment: Sidenote: To keep namespace clean, it's generally recommended to undef X-macro (`THING`) immediately after the use.

Comment: How important is the exact sequencing shown?  If the all inclusive list must be in exactly the order shown, it's harder than if the order is flexible.  But the suggestion you've already got goes to the core of the issue. You need different macro names so that you can expand them differently depending on context. (I'd probably use names like `THING_FRUIT` rather than the names suggested, but names are malleable.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I like user694733's solution, but you mentioned that "it's harder than if the order is flexible".  Now I'm curious: what's the technique?

Comment: Oh, I'd think in terms of `#define THING_DEFINITIONS FRUITY_THINGS CRUNCHY_THINGS` and have `#define FRUITY_THINGS THING(apple, true) THING(pear, true) THING(mango, true)` and `#define CRUNCHY_THINGS THING(cadillac, false)`.  Then if I didn't want the crunchy things, I'd have various choices — referencing FRUITY_THINGS directly or redefining THING_DEFINITIONS to only reference FRUITY_THINGS.  But, at the nuts and bolts level, this is still the same basic idea (multiple macros) — it's just minor tweaks on the mechanics.  It might be more compelling if there were more attributes in the data.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ah - I see what you mean.  Yes, my use case is more complex: I have to keep external indexes in sync with slots in an internal data table.  The external indexes are sparse, the internal data table is dense.

Comment: Don't forget the benefits of designated initializers for getting data into the right slots in arrays.  This can be extremely helpful.  Or it may not be relevant to you.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: +1 for initializers.  My macros expand first into a struct definition (which defines in-memory layout of state) and second into an initialized array of attributes (where each attribute is contained in a bit field struct).  Works like a champ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generate new macro name according the `is_fruit`:

```
// Options
#define THING_true(name) #name,
#define THING_false(name)

// Combine symbols
#define CONCAT(a, b) a ## b

// Final macro
#define THING(name, is_fruit)  CONCAT(THING_, is_fruit) (name)
```

This will expand to:

```
THING_true(apple)
THING_true(pear)
THING_false(caddilac)
THING_true(mango)
```

Which will finally expand to:

```
"apple",
"pear",

"mango",
```

I did a small test on Ideone: http://ideone.com/TDR2WO

Comment: Considering how quickly I managed to come up with this, I fear that I have done *way* too much macro abuse in my life :-/

Comment: There's no such thing as too much macro abuse :)!  And thanks for the ideone.com site (I knew of godbolt.org, but that's c++ specific).